# Android - ViewPager scrolling resets

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` in my app that houses a horizontal layout of images to implement a Paginated gallery.

When I test the view alone, i.e. as the main view of an activity, it works fine. However, when I include this as part of another layout, the scrolling (or flicking) becomes weird. If seems to reset to its original position around halfway through a swipe (really quick flicks are the only thing I've gotten to work so far).

Any ideas what the problem could be ?

Just in case it is of any relevance, the view is inflated from XML and added in a `PagerAdapter` inherited class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, `ViewPager` and other scrolling items don't play well together by default. When I have to do such things, I typically subclass `ViewPager` to make something that's aware of children that can scroll. Then in my `onInterceptTouchEvent()` I check whether the hit rect is within that child and don't intercept the touch event so the child has a whack at it. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Override to not intercept touch events within our scroller if it exists.
 */
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(scrollerId != 0) {
        View scroller = findViewById(scrollerId);
        if(scroller != null) {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            scroller.getHitRect(rect);
            if(rect.contains((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Then all you need is a way to set that `scrollerId` (a simple public method works).

Note another way is if you are using a `ScrollView` for *vertically* scrolling elements with `ViewPager` *children*, you'll need to go a different direction. Have a subclass of `ScrollView` that detects vertical scrolling directions and bails for horizontal scrolling so the `ViewPager` picks it up.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
            lastX = curX;
            lastY = curY;
            if (xDistance > yDistance)
                return false;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Figured it would come to down to MotionEvents... never understood that stuff much but maybe the sample code will help me get there... I'm just gonna try it out now

Comment: Yup... that works. However, since I'm beginning to understand this now, I reckon I'm going to have another problem soon since I intend to have the Images within the ViewPager clickable and they need to start activities. Any tips on that.... I reckon I should catch ACTION_MOVE and let the ACTION_DOWN go similar to your second example.

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't be too much of an issue. Set your `onClickListener` on the `ImageView` and make sure to set them as clickable (either in your XML layout or in code) and you should be okay. The click action is a slightly different path than the move events.