# ViewPager (and its swiping) in the header of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, gestures

I have a ViewPager inside a header of a ListView, and I noticed that, when you're swiping the viewpager, if the finger moves a little bit on the Y axis, the event gets canceled (I guess it's intercepted by the listview?).
The only way to swipe a picture, is to just slide your finger through few pixels, since there'll be less probabilities that you're moving your finger along the Y axis.

Is there a way to make the listview not to intercept the Y axis events in case they happened in the viewpager? I don't even know if this is what I need anyways.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to intercept touch event

Take a look at this post [Android - ViewPager scrolling resets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179314/android-viewpager-scrolling-resets)

hope it helps

good luck